# Finding $\lambda$

Tags: trigonometry

If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, $\delta$ are smallest positive angle in ascending order of magnitude which have their sines equal to positive quantity $\lambda$ , then if

$4\sin\frac{\alpha}{2}+3\sin\frac{\beta}{2}+2\sin\frac{\gamma}{2}+\sin\frac{\delta}{2} = 2\sqrt{1+\lambda}$

then $\lambda$ = ?

Options-

(1)$\sin\alpha$

(2)$\sin\beta$

(3)$\sin\gamma$

(4)$\sin\delta$

My Approach -> I am just not able to understand if it's given that $\sin\alpha=\sin\beta=\sin\gamma=\sin\delta = \lambda$ , aren't all the options correct  ? Yet my answer is wrong !!

Comment: What answer are you getting? Also, the question is confusing because of what you have said  i.e. the options all seem to be equal.

Comment: I am confused as I assume that all the options are correct !!

Comment: Their sines equal to positive quantity $\lambda$? do you mean $\sin(x)=\lambda, \forall x \in \left\{ \alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta \right\}$?

Comment: $\sin \alpha = \sin \beta$ does not imply $\sin \alpha/2 = \sin \beta /2$. Were those all, and the only, options?

Comment: Angles having their sines equal doesnt mean that the angles are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See we have ascending order for positive sines as $a,\pi-a,2\pi+a,3\pi-a $ as sine is positive only in first two quadrants .Now these are values of $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\delta $ plugging in and simplifying we get $\sin (\alpha/2)+\cos (\alpha/2)=\sqrt {1+\lambda} $ thus squaring we get $\lambda=\sin (\alpha) $